# Decreasing training loss, stable validation loss - is the model overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network

Does my model overfit? I would be sure it overfitted, if the validation loss increased heavily, while the training loss decreased. However the validation loss is nearly stable, so I am not sure. Can you please help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- I assume that you're using different hyperparameters? Perhaps save
  the parameters and resume with a different set of hyperparameters.
  This comment really depends on how you're doing hyperparameter
  optimization.
- Try with different training/test splits. It might be idiosyncratic.
  Especially with so few epochs.
- Depending on how costly it is to train the model and evaluate it,
  consider bagging your models, akin to how a random forest operates.
  In others words, fit your model to many different train/test splits,
  and average the model outputs, either in terms of a majority
  classification vote, or an averaging of the predicted probabilities.
  In this case, I'd err on the side of a slightly overfit model,
  because of the way that averaging can mitigate overfitting. But I
  wouldn't train to death either, unless you're going to fit very very
  many neural nets, and somehow ensure that you're decorrelating them
  akin to the method of random subspaces from random forests.